# Dropna is surprisingly not woking?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

It is super wired, I was going to drop the NAN for features with missing less than 5%. After I dropped it, I wanted to see if it worked or not, I surprisingly found out that I couldn't drop NAN for these variables and the NAN values are even more ??

please tell me where I am wrong

Thank you so much

[image]

Comment: Please use tags appropriately; this is a `pandas` question, and has nothing to do with `machine-learning` (edited).

Answer (score 0):

Why the code doesn't work: you have more columns than in `dropna_list`. Then you tell pandas to delete the rows in `train_set[drop_list]`. But these rows are still kept in `train_set` because it contains more columns. Basically, `train_set` tries to merge the data from columns outside of `drop_list` and with modified columns. Missing subrows are imputed by zeros.

How to fix it? Use masks. You can determine what rows are deleted:

```
mask = training_set[drop_list.pop(0)].isna()
for col in drop_list:
    mask = mask & training_set[col].isna()
training_set = training_set[mask]
```